# Upgrade certification from MCSA sql server 2012/2014 to MCSE SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

All,

I would like to know what path should I chose in order to achieve MCSE for SQL 2016. I already completed MCSA certification for SQL 2012/2014 and would like to upgrade it to MCSE SQL 2016/2017. Kindly, let me know what is the best approach for this. Is there any direct path or do I need to take n number of exams to get that certification. Also, would like to know what resources or links you'll can share that can help me possibly get through to that certification...most likely in first attempt. I only would choose one exam but it should be more focused towards honing my existing DBA skills.

https://buildazure.com/2017/02/14/mcse-data-management-and-analytics-certification/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move from MCSA to MCSE you would need to take one of the following exams (As of Jan-2017) which one you take is entirely up to you - though if you want to use SQL on Azure I'd recommend taking one of the cloud-based exams:

- Exam 70-473: Designing and Implementing Cloud Data Platform Solutions
- Exam 70-475: Designing and Implementing Big Data Analytics Solutions
- Exam 70-464: Developing Microsoft SQL Server Databases
- Exam 70-465: Designing Database Solutions for Microsoft SQL Server
- Exam 70-466: Implementing Data Models and Reports with Microsoft SQL Server
- Exam 70-467: Designing Business Intelligence Solutions with Microsoft SQL Server
- Exam 70-762: Developing SQL Databases
- Exam 70-767: Implementing a Data Warehouse using SQL
- Exam 70-768: Developing SQL Data Models
- Exam 70-773: Analyzing Big Data with Microsoft R
- Exam 70-774: Perform Cloud Data Science with Azure Machine Learning
- Exam 70-775: Perform Data Engineering on Microsoft Azure HDInsight

You can find more information on the [Microsoft Learning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/mcse-data-management-analytics.aspx#cp-section3-head) page for that exam track which also has recommended learning material and optional courses.

Regardless of which exam or training method you decide to take, there is no substitute for experience and you will find it much easier to pass the exams if you have hands-on experience with the product and specialization that you choose.

Comment: I get that but is there an exam out of the ones listed that more aligns towards the DBA skills.

Comment: You would need to look at the requirements of each exam and see which one fits your intended goal. The MCSE exams are more about the design/development and analytics parts which were not available as exams before.